# Mask part of XML with dynamic element names using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to mask part of xml file (selected elements). those element will be in separate xml file (parameter). i have working solution but there i have hard coded tag name. any help is appreciate to make this dynamic

xml payload

```
<results>
   <ready>yes</ready>
   <student>
      <accounts>
         <boa>23423423423424</boa>
         <dcu>345345353535</dcu>
      </accounts>
      <cardState>
         <approved>true</approved>
         <approvedacc>
            <element>232323433233</element>
         </approvedacc>
         <refund>
            <element>200</element>
         </refund>
      </cardState>
      <cource>
         <marks>
            <element>A+</element>
         </marks>
         <total>
            <element>20000</element>
         </total>
      </cource>
      <created>true</created>
      <firstName>john doe</firstName>
      <ssn>123456</ssn>
   </student>
</results>
```

expected output

```
<results>
   <ready>yes</ready>
   <student>
      <accounts>
         ****************
      </accounts>
      <cardState>
         <approved>true</approved>
         <approvedacc>
            <element>232323433233</element>
         </approvedacc>
         <refund>
            <element>200</element>
         </refund>
      </cardState>
      <cource>
         <marks>
            <element>A+</element>
         </marks>
         <total>
            <element>20000</element>
         </total>
      </cource>
      <created>true</created>
      <firstName>**********</firstName>
      <ssn>123456</ssn>
   </student>
</results>
```

key xml file (elements to be masked)

```
<keys>
<key>accounts</key>
<key>firstName</key>
</keys>
```

my working solution is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="mask" select="'********'"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//results/student/accounts/*">
<xsl:value-of select="$mask"/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output

```
<results>
    <ready>yes</ready>
    <student>
        <accounts>****************</accounts>
        <cardState>
            <approved>true</approved>
            <approvedacc>
                <element>232323433233</element>
            </approvedacc>
            <refund>
                <element>200</element>
            </refund>
        </cardState>
        <cource>
            <marks>
                <element>A+</element>
            </marks>
            <total>
                <element>20000</element>
            </total>
        </cource>
        <created>true</created>
        <firstName>john doe</firstName>
        <ssn>123456</ssn>
    </student>
</results>
```

if it is xslt 1.0 solution that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-keys" select="'keys.xml'"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name()=document($path-to-keys)/keys/key">********</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

The above assumes you are passing the **path** to a `keys.xml` file as the parameter. If the parameter is the **contents** of the file, then try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="keys"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name()=exsl:node-set($keys)/keys/key">********</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming your method of passing the parameter manages to pass the contents of the `keys.xml` file **as XML** (i.e. not as a *string* containing escaped markup).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. if i pass this xml file (keys) to  path-to-keys parameter from externally how should <xsl:when test="name()=document($path-to-keys)/keys/key">********</xsl:when> should change? I mean just assume xml file (keys) is the value of the parameter. (path-to-keys)

Comment: its worked. it says node-set is not there. so i implemented it inside xslt

Comment: @DerekNoble I am glad you made it work, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: can I embed xml file in to other xslt and take that it via xsl:include? if so how can access those keys/key from that xsl:when ? because your assumption was correct. my xml file is not AS XML. i checked ur solution with hard code xml.

Comment: You can either embed the XML in the XSLT stylesheet itself, or place it in a separate file and have the stylesheet read from there (that's what my first answer does). `xsl:include` is meant to read XSL instructions, not XML data.